# nouveau preventing shutdown after suspend-resume. What can I do?

Tags: nvidia, shutdown, nouveau

My ASUS X556U laptop has two video cards: Intel's HD Graphics 520 and NVIDIA GeForce 940MX.

There is a `nouveau` bug, when `nouveau` preventing shutdown after suspend-resume. I found [another report](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=99889) regarding this bug. On shutdown I am getting error messages like this one:

```
"nouveau 0000:01:00.0: Xorg[1039]: failed to idle channel 3[Xorg[1039]"
```

So, I have to turn off without shutdown that is unsafe. (The proprietary NVIDIA driver is even worse. I cannot resume after suspend).
Could someone advise any workaround?

Comment: After update to 18.04 this shutdown problem disappeared.